# Python - how do I create a list of letters from a string with special characters?

Tags: python, list, encoding, utf-8, letters

I want to create a list of letters from this string in python:

```
string = 'utf✮fff'
```

I have tried this:

```
>>> string = "utf✮fff"
>>> print list(string)
['u', 't', 'f', '\xe2', '\x9c', '\xae', 'f', 'f', 'f']
```

However it should look like this:

```
['u', 't', 'f', '\xe2\x9c\xae', 'f', 'f', 'f']
```

Does anyone know how to create this output? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're dealing with a byte string. Use a unicode string if you want Python to be aware of individual *characters*: `u'utf✮fff'`

Comment: Thank you! It worked, how can I apply this on string variables? like: `unicodestring = string.encode('unicode')`

Comment: @DanielTremer "unicode" is not an encoding. You have to use var = unicode(var)

Comment: @DanielTremer: unicodestring = string.decode('utf8'). But don't actually call it string, that's the name of a standard library module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use unicode strings:

```
string = u'utf✮fff'
print list(string)

[u'u', u't', u'f', u'\u272e', u'f', u'f', u'f']


string = 'utf✮fff'
string = unicode(string)
print list(string)

[u'u', u't', u'f', u'\u272e', u'f', u'f', u'f']
```

Note that in your case, you will have to set the

```
# coding: utf8
```

header.

Comment: Works! Did it this way without setting the header: `string = 'utf✮fff'
string = string.decode('utf-8')
string = unicode(string)
print list(string)`

Comment: @DanielTremer That's valid too :) Note you can also use sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')